# Thule jogging kit twisted?

Tags: adjustment, quick-release

I recently bought a Thule CX2 Chariot with jogging kit. The front wheel tracks to the right.

The jogging kit consists of two aluminium arms, a wheel and a quick release skewer.

When I look at the arms, installed side by side, one side is higher the other.

Any thoughts on how to balance them out?

Answer (score 3):

One arm has an adjusting knob that forwards/retracts it, therefore correcting the trajectory deviation. See the blue Knob and the black plastic that it moves on the picture bellow.

[image]

No need to overadjust it, since small changes in how the wheel and/or arms are inserted will change the trajectory center the next time. Just make it good enough and correct small deviations by pushing the cart unevenly.

Comment: I guess this is for a more recent version of the kit than I have.